# Setting up wcf netTcpBinding with minimum configuration

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding

I have a service which will be self hosted. Multiple clients connect ot the service and consume it. I am leaning towards tcp as it provides sessions without any extra code and also hopefully a perpormance boost.

The clients(wpf application) all have a username and password that I store in a db on the server. Now the question is how do I set this binding up? The security requirements are not very high and I'd prefer a simple solution.

I am very new to wcf and services in general. I gathered that I could use certificates for authentication, but have no clue how they work. Don't know much about windows authentication either.

To recap:

I store username/password on server.
I need to get the tcpBinding working over the internet with as little configuration as possible
Security is not a major concern
Client computers not in my domain.

If the question is too broad, links to resources, even pointers to what I should be looking at would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: nettcp is intranet binding, if you want internet binding you need to choose from ohter binding types like basichttpbinding

Comment: Thanx @user6130
After researching a little bit on the internet, I did find out that netTcpBinding is genrally not used over the internet, but theoretically it is possible to do so.

I suppose I shall have to look at other default bindings or consider custom binding(binary over http)[link]:(http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/02/22/WCF-Enable-Binary-Encoding-Over-Http.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario you should use basichttpbinding over https.

The reasons for this are:

- You will be sending data over the internet (basichttpbinding is simplest in this case)
- You will be sending username and password over the internet (use https/SSL to stop these going over in clear text)

Here is an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx

To get the https to work set the security mode to transport.

Comment: thank you for the response. I was looking into other default bindings with wcf and found out that wsHttp does support sessions easily enough and it can send the messages in binary(not exactly, but use MTOM which I gathered was close enough) as well. 

I certainly would need to set the security as I am sending username/password on the wire.

Thanx again for the reply.